# Deny non-local Apache requests that match a specific URL pattern

Tags: apache, apache2, configuration, 403-forbidden

I need to configure my Apache (2.4) in a way, that It prevents answering requests that

1. don't come from the same IP as the server
2. match a specific pattern in the URL

In pseudocode it must look something like this, but I'm having a hard time translating this in valid Apache config syntax

```
<If "%{CLIENT_IP} != %{SERVER_IP} &&  %{REQUEST_URL} contains 'abcde' ">
  Require all denied
</If>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list of allowed IPs and then compare the page or directory accessed against it.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Remote_Addr 192.0.2.4 allow_ip #AllowedServer1
SetEnvIfNoCase Remote_Addr 192.0.2.6 allow_ip #AllowedServer2

<Directory /home/YOURSITE/public_html/secret/>
    <RequireAll>
        require env allow_ip
    </RequireAll>
</Directory>
```

Following the above code, access to the directory **example.com/secret** will only be allowed for IPs **192.0.2.4 and 192.0.2.6**. Apache will deny access with a 403 error to all other visitors.

Comment: How does this answer the question.  The OP is not asking about particular IP addresses, but rather a pattern.